# Change Text Color of Number Picker via State Selector

Tags: android, styles, textcolor, android-number-picker

I am trying to change the text color of NumberPicker !

i want different colors at different states , if state is enable and different color for state is disabled.

here is my number picker code :

```
 <NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/NumberOfWebsitesPicker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleX="0.75"
                    style="@style/MyStyle"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    android:scaleY="0.75" />
```

here is my text_color.xml  under

> Res->Color Direcoty

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#9D9FA2" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="#FAFAFA" />

</selector>
```

now here is my style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>

        <!--  It should be true otherwise action mode will not overlay toolbar -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <!--  For Custom Action Mode Background Color/Drawable -->
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>

        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color</item>

        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/divider_color</item>

        <item name="android:divider">@color/divider_color</item>

        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_size_14</item>

        <item name="actionBarSize">56dp</item>

        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/Spinner_Item_Style</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/Spinner_DropDown_Item_Style</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerStyle</item>


    </style>


    <style name="Divider">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/divider_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DividerThin">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">2px</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/divider_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Vertical_divider" parent="DividerThin">
        <item name="android:layout_width">2px</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/divider_color</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Vertical_divider_thick" parent="Divider">
        <item name="android:layout_width">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/divider_color</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Spinner_Item_Style">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Spinner_DropDown_Item_Style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/unit_8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/unit_8dp</item>

    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">@color/divider_color</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
    </style>


    <style name="MyStyle">

        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/text_color</item>

    </style>


</resources>
```

now here it works very well only once and next time when Number Picker is disabled it keeps its color White and doesn't change color with its disabled color declared in text_color selector file.

I am not getting that why its working only once ,

if Numberpicker is disabled onCreateView it gets the color of disable state
when i manually disable picker by pressing button it changes color of text to disabled color  but when I enable it , it takes color of enable color and change value and disable it again , it doesn't go to disabled color.

it works only once, and doesn't work after changing value of picker.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using the below code:

```
fun setEnabledNumberPicker(numberPicker: NumberPicker, isEnable : Boolean) {
    numberPicker.isEnabled = isEnable
    val enablePickerColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.textEnabled)
    val disablePickerColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.textDisabled)

    try {
        val selectorWheelPaintField: Field = numberPicker.javaClass
            .getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint")
        selectorWheelPaintField.isAccessible = true
        if (isEnable)
            (selectorWheelPaintField.get(numberPicker) as Paint).color = enablePickerColor
        else
            (selectorWheelPaintField.get(numberPicker) as Paint).color = disablePickerColor
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    val count = numberPicker.childCount
    for (i in 0 until count) {
        val child = numberPicker.getChildAt(i)
        if (child is EditText) {
            if (isEnable)
                child.setTextColor(enablePickerColor)
            else
                child.setTextColor(disablePickerColor)

        }
    }
    numberPicker.invalidate()
}
```